# How can I add a dictionary inside an existing dictionary ,Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have the below script in which I have dictionary `d` with `d[domain]` date and `dns_dic` dictionary with `domain` as keys and `rdata = ip` as value.

```
Expected result:
```

I am wondering how can I make the key of dictionary `dns_dic` as `tuple` of domain,date (key values of dictionary d) and value of `dns_dic` as `ip`, like
 `dns_dic = {(domain1,date1):ip1,(domain2,date2):ip2}` etc.

```
dns_dic = defaultdict(set)
d = {domain1:date1,domain2:date2, ..}

    if domain in d:
        for i in d[domain]:
            if jdata.get('time_first') <= i <= jdata.get('time_last'):
            dns_dic[dom].update(jdata.get('rdata', []))
```

This is how `jdata` looks like:

```
{"rrname":"c.000a.biz.","time_last":1400243400,"time_first":1388645949,"rdata":["50.21.180.100"]}
{"rrname":"c.000a.biz.","time_last":1389133600,"time_first":1389133600,"rdata":["50.21.180.100"]}
{"rrname": "0001211.com.","time_last":1407101755,"time_first":1389074193,"rdata":["50.21.180.100"]}
```

Comment: What is `dom`? If it's a `list` it can be cast to `tuple` using `tuple(dom)` before adding it as a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question by example, this is the straightforward way to add `tuple` as `dict` key:

```
# create a dict   
d = {}
# add tuple as key with some value
d[('some domain', 'some date')] = 'some ip'
print d
```

Output:

```
{('some domain', 'some date'): 'some ip'}
```

To cast a `list` to `tuple` use `tuple(lst)` where `lst` is your list.

Answer (score 0):

you can get `tuples` of `(key, value)` with `dict.items()` method.

you can do somthing like:

```
for item in d.items(): # item is (key,value) tuple
    domain,date = item
    for jd in jdata:
       if jd.get('time_first') <= date <= jd.get('time_last'):
           dns_dic[item] = jd.get('rdata',[])
```

assuming the variables are like

```
dns_dic = {}
d = {"domain1":1389074195,"domain2":1388645951,"domain3":1389133601}

jdata = [
{"rrname":"c.000a.biz.","time_last":1400243400,"time_first":1388645949,
                                                  "rdata":["50.21.180.100"]},
{"rrname":"c.000a.biz.","time_last":1389133600,"time_first":1389133600,
                                                  "rdata":["50.21.180.100"]},
{"rrname": "0001211.com.","time_last":1407101755,"time_first":1389074193,
                                                   "rdata":["50.21.180.100"]},
 ]
```